# How to extract XML elements stored in a column of type NVARCHAR into seperate columns

Tags: sql-server, xml

**Scenario**: in SQL Server, I have a table `[users]` with columns `[id] int` and `userdetails nvarchar(max)` which contains data like:

```
<Attributes>
  <Map>
    <entry key="displayName" value="Administrator"/>
    <entry key="email" value="joe.blow@google.com"/>
    <entry key="firstname" value="Joe"/>
    <entry key="lastname" value="Blow"/>
  </Map>
</Attributes>
```

In a query I'd would like to extract as individual columns, like so:

```
displayName | email | firstname | lastname
```

What syntax could I use to accomplish this? (preferably in a performant manner as I have lots of queries to perform against potentially large tables....but even getting it working *at all* would be lovely)

What I've tried so far:  2+ hours of googling and trying various different syntax with no success (failure due to a variety of error messages, the resolution of each also being unsuccessful).

A secondary question might be whether there is a way to accommodate possibly missing key values in some rows (ie: email may not be specified, at all)

Comment: Whatever you do, it would be *a lot better performing* if you would store your XML as `XML` datatype (instead of `NVARCHAR(MAX)`); you can save yourself a costly conversion, and the `XML` datatype is storing the data in an optimized fashion, which uses less storage space, and allows direct manipulation of your XML structures

Comment: Check out http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/XML/87685/

Comment: @marc_s  Agreed, in my case I'm running against a legacy system so don't have that option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use  SQL XML functions and XPath query. This is an example.

```
declare @tbl table(id int, userdetails nvarchar(max))
insert @tbl(id,userdetails)
values(1,'<Attributes>
  <Map>
    <entry key="displayName" value="Administrator"/>
    <entry key="email" value="joe.blow@google.com"/>
    <entry key="firstname" value="Joe"/>
    <entry key="lastname" value="Blow"/>
  </Map>
</Attributes>')

;with tbl as (
select id,cast(userdetails as xml) ud
from @tbl)
select id,
t.v.value('entry[@key="displayName"][1]/@value','nvarchar(100)') displayName,
t.v.value('entry[@key="email"][1]/@value','nvarchar(100)') email,
t.v.value('entry[@key="firstname"][1]/@value','nvarchar(100)') firstname,
t.v.value('entry[@key="lastname"][1]/@value','nvarchar(100)') lastname
from tbl 
cross apply ud.nodes('Attributes/Map') t(v)
```

Comment: very sleek, I was trying to solve it too but was struggling :)  +1

Comment: If this had one more level of nesting, for example:
<Attributes><Map><AnotherLevel>, would it then be like:

select id,
t.v.a.value.....
cross apply ud.nodes('Attributes/Map/AnotherLevel') t(v)(a)  ?

Comment: in `.nodes` go to the level just above `entry`. Try and succeed ;)

Comment: Note with `//entry` you can get to the entry elements regardless of where they are in the tree. That can be dangerous if you only want them at a particular location. However, it can be helpful if your XML is consistent and you want all of them, but don't want to have to drill down through a dozen layers to get there. See the W3Schools page [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)

Comment: @bzier Good practice is to use exact XPath. In the current OP the idea is to stop exactly one level above `entry`. `.nodes('//entry')` returns 4 rows and the OP expects one.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Sorry, I should have been more clear. You can cross apply to the root node `ud.nodes('/')` and grab the value of entry using the `//` like `t.v.value('(//entry[@key="displayName"])[1]/@value','nvarchar(100)')`

Comment: But yes, the exact XPath is better in most situations. Just wanted to point out an additional possibility.