# Possible to extract the *distinct* keys (across all rows) stored within XML in a column?

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a table [users] with columns:

```
[id] int  
[userdetails] nvarchar(max)
```

[userdetails] contains data like:

```
<Attributes>
  <Map>
    <entry key="displayName" value="Administrator"/>
    <entry key="email" value="joe.blow@google.com"/>
    <entry key="firstname" value="Joe"/>
    <entry key="lastname" value="tdehdgthrth"/>
    <entry key="another1" value="rthrth"/>
    <entry key="another7" value="etdsryhntdhetdyh"/>
    <entry key="anotherWhatever" value="6546544"/>
  </Map>
</Attributes>
```

Each row can contain a different combination of count of key/value elements.

**In a query I would like to extract a list of all the distinct (across all rows) KEY values.  Is this even possible?**

I had earlier asked a similar question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50281264/8678

The syntax for querying **specific** elements from the above is like this:

```
declare @tbl table(id int, userdetails nvarchar(max))
insert @tbl(id,userdetails)
values(1,'<Attributes>
  <Map>
    <entry key="displayName" value="Administrator"/>
    <entry key="email" value="joe.blow@google.com"/>
    <entry key="firstname" value="Joe"/>
    <entry key="lastname" value="Blow"/>
  </Map>
</Attributes>')

;with tbl as (
select id,cast(userdetails as xml) ud
from @tbl)
select id,
t.v.value('entry[@key="displayName"][1]/@value','nvarchar(100)') displayName,
t.v.value('entry[@key="email"][1]/@value','nvarchar(100)') email,
t.v.value('entry[@key="firstname"][1]/@value','nvarchar(100)') firstname,
t.v.value('entry[@key="lastname"][1]/@value','nvarchar(100)') lastname
from tbl 
cross apply ud.nodes('Attributes/Map') t(v)
```

The obvious problem with this is that it requires one to know the available values and hardcode them within the SQL, whereas what I'm trying to do here is **discover what the distinct set of possible key values is**.

Comment: You should store your XML as `XML` and not as `NVARCHAR(MAX)`...

Answer (score 2):

> In a query I would like to extract a list of all the distinct (across all rows) KEY values. Is this even possible?

---

> What I'm trying to do here is discover what the distinct set of possible key values is.

---

This will produce the list of distinct keys from all rows (Note: I'm not sure how long each key value may be, but this will only grab 100 characters; change as necessary):

```
;WITH tbl AS (
    SELECT id, cast(userdetails as xml) ud
    FROM testSo)
SELECT DISTINCT
    t.v.value('(@key)[1]','nvarchar(100)') anEntryKey
FROM tbl 
CROSS APPLY ud.nodes('//entry') t(v)
```

---

If you need to get more information about where each came from (which ID), you can get the (non-distinct) list like this:

```
;WITH tbl AS (
    SELECT id, cast(userdetails as xml) ud
    FROM testSo)
SELECT
    id,
    t.v.value('(@key)[1]','nvarchar(100)') anEntryKey
FROM tbl 
CROSS APPLY ud.nodes('//entry') t(v)
```

I tested these on SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ad557/1) using SQL Server 2017.

Comment: As Alex pointed out on your other question, it may be better practice to get to the exact node you want. Example: `CROSS APPLY ud.nodes('/Attributes/Map/entry') t(v)`